# What is the implication that $\| \cdot \|_2$ and $\| \cdot \|_\infty$ are equivalent norms on $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Given $\mathbb{X}$ = $\mathbb{R^2}$, consider $\| \cdot \|_2$ and $\| \cdot \|_\infty$

We can show that

$\| x \|_\infty \leq \| x \|_2 \leq \sqrt2 \| x \|_\infty$

Hence $\| \cdot \|_2$ and $\| \cdot \|_\infty$ are equivalent norms

Is there some deeper implication regarding this particular relationship? Why do we care if two norms are equivalent in this sense?

Comment: All norms are equivalent in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: As an implication: they define the same topology, and thus open sets are the same under both (meaning, among other things, that a function continuous with regard to one topological space is also continuous for the other).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by [Clement C](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/75808/clement-c) in the comments: Equivalent norms induce the same topology. Also the other direction of implication is true: When two norms induce the same topology then they are equivalent.

Take two norms $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ on a vector space and you ask yourself: When are the topologies from those norms the same? This is the case when open sets for $\|\cdot\|_1$ are also open in $\|\cdot\|_2$ and vice versa. This is the case when in each open ball in $\|\cdot\|_1$ contains an open ball of $\|\cdot\|_2$ and the other way around. From this you can prove that there are constants $c$ and $C$ such that $c\|\cdot\|_1 \le \|\cdot\|_2 \le C \|\cdot\|_1$.

So the answer to your question is: Two norms are equivalent iff their induced topologies are the same.

What is the benefit if two topologies are the same? If a "topological property" is valid for one norm, then it is valid for the other norm. For example:

- Open, closed and compact sets are the same.
- If a sequence converges in one norm, it converges also in the other norm.
- If a sequence is a Cauchy sequence in one norm it is Cauchy in the other.
- ...

Answer (score 2):

Some application of this result and more generally that all norms are equivalent on finite dimensional spaces:

- The compact subspaces are the closed bounded spaces.
- All linear maps are continuous. More generally all multilinear maps are continuous.
- All linear maps are bounded on the unit ball.

Comment: If space means vector space, no subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be bounded...